# Find the exact length of the curve. $x = 1 + 12t^2,\ y = 4 + 8t^3,\ 0 ≤ t ≤ 1$

Tags: calculus

Find the exact length of the curve. $x = 1 + 12t^2,\    y = 4 + 8t^3,\    0 ≤ t ≤ 1$

My answer was 245 units; however, it is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of the curve is

$(x',y')=(24t,24t^2)$

defined for $t\in[0,1]$. Then

$\sqrt{||(x',y')||}=24\sqrt{t^2+t^4} $

Therefore the lenght of the curve is

$L=\int_{0}^{1} 24\sqrt{t^2+t^4}dt= \int_0^1 24t\sqrt{1+t^2}dt$.

By using the change of variable $u=t^2+1$ and $du=\frac{tdt}{2}$ you have that

$L=12\int_1^2\sqrt{u}\ du = 12(\frac{2}{3})(u^{3/2})|_{1}^2 = 8(\sqrt{8}-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a theorem that we can employ:
If $[a,b] \subset \Bbb{R}$ and if $r: [a,b] \to \Bbb{R}^{n}$ is continuously differentiable on $]a,b[$, then $r$ is rectifiable and its arc length is
$\int_{a}^{b}|r'(t)|dt$.

If $r: t \mapsto (1+12t^{2}, 4+8t^{3})$ on $[0,1]$, then $r$ is the curve under consideration; clearly $r$ is continuously differentiable on $]0,1[$. But
$|r'(t)| = 24t(1+t^{2})^{1/2}$ for all $t \in ]0,1[$; hence
$$
\int_{0}^{1}|r'(t)|dt = 24\int_{0}^{1}t(1+t^{2})^{1/2}dt = 12\int_{1}^{2}(1+t^{2})^{1/2}d(1+t^{2}) = 8(\sqrt{8}-1).
$$